# PHP script output not shown in Firefox

Tags: php, html, firefox

The output following HTML doesn't show the output of `echo` from the PHP script on Firefox. What is the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<body>  
<form method="post">  
Enter First Number:  
<input type="number" name="number1" /><br><br>  
Enter Second Number:  
<input type="number" name="number2" /><br><br>  
<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">  
</form>  
<?php  
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))  
    {  
        $number1 = $_POST['number1'];  
        $number2 = $_POST['number2'];  
        $sum =  $number1+$number2;     
echo "The sum of $number1 and $number2 is: ".$sum;   
}  
?>  
</body>  
</html>
```

This is the page that i see as i click on the Add button:

[image]

So basically nothing happens, and i get back to the original page.

I am using Firefox version 69.0.1 on Debian and using XAMPP as my local testing server.

Comment: Works for me in firefox. What version, what os, what is the output in ff?

Comment: What do you see if you do "view page source"? As far as I can tell by looking at the code, I don't see any reason for it not to work.

Comment: Does it work for you in other browsers?

Comment: Also NEVER call anything in a form "submit" if you ever want JavaScript to interact with the submit event

Comment: Browser window observations are insufficient for debugging.

Comment: Wrong dupe. There is no PHP showing on page

Comment: @mario true. Did not consider that. We can ask him

Answer (score 0):

Works good for me in Firefox. Using XAMPP As Server [image]

Try Changing your HTML code to the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    Enter First Number:
    <input type="number" name="number1" /><br><br>
    Enter Second Number:
    <input type="number" name="number2" /><br><br>
    <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $number1 = $_POST['number1'];
    $number2 = $_POST['number2'];
    $sum =  $number1+$number2;
    echo "The sum of $number1 and $number2 is: ".$sum;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not an answer. What did you change that made OPs problem go away? Also never call anything "submit" in a form